# Python. The way how to find out the element's order based on selected variable in list

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, python-requests

I would find out the order of element in the list, which is selected based on any variable.

I have variables: first "users", where are names of poeple and second "values", where are any values of the people (just values which belong to names of list). Then i created another variable and in this variable I choose, which one of the elements will be printed to terminal.
The variable "fer" I found on the internet and I don't understand excatly what is it doing.
I'm confused now. I hope, it was understandable, that where's the problem.

Here is any code:

```
users=['Peter', "Georgo", "Mike"]
values=[600, 700, 800]

print("Users: {}\nTheir Values: {}".format(users,values))

vstup=str(input("Choose the user: "))

if vstup == "Peter":
    val=values[0]
if vstup == str("Georgo"):
    val=values[1]
if vstup == "Mike":
    subs=str(values[2])

fer = list(filter(lambda x: vstup in x, users)) 
print("Selected: " + str(fer))
print("His value is: {}.".format(values[0]))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can directly use the `index` function, so `ind = users.index('Mike')` is 2, and `values[ind]` is 800.

You should look at dictionaries instead.  They fit better, work faster, and are easier to type:

```
users = { 'Peter': 600, 'Georgeo': 700, 'Mike': 800  }
print(f'Names = {list(users.keys())}')
print(f'Values = {list(users.values())}')
print(f'Georgeo number : {users["Georgeo"]}')
for user, value in users.items():
   print(f' {user} has {value}')
```

gives

```
Names = ['Peter', 'Georgeo', 'Mike']
Value = [600, 700, 800]
Georgeo number : 700
 Peter has 600
 Georgeo has 700
 Mike has 800
```

Answer (score 1):

Are you looking for which position "Peter" or "Georgo" are in the list? is so use the .count method like so

```
count = users.count(vstup)
print(count)
```

This will print their position as base 0

If your looking to print the correct value base on position, you simply need to

```
print(val)
```

as you set them in the if statements